# Dropdown list filter in Angular HTML file

Tags: html, angular, filter, dropdown, html-select

```
<div class="panel-body rc-bl rc-br">         
    <form ngForm class="form-group">
         <div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">

              <!-- Col 1 start -->
              <div style="display: inline-block; width: 130px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; vertical-align: middle;" class="labelRed12">
                    <label for="wslr_name">Wholesaler:</label>
               </div>

               <!-- Col 2 start --> 
               <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; vertical-align: middle">
                     <select style="width: 250px;" id="wslr_name" name="wslr_name"  [(ngModel)]="Group.wslr_name" (change)=wslrSelect(Group.wslr_name)>
                            <option *ngFor="let c of wslrList.result">{{c.A}}</option>
                     </select>
                </div>
```

This is the HTML file in Angular. I need dropdown list based on filtering.
If I give "A" in the search box, I should get all the data starting with "A" only.

Answer (score 0):

There is an NPM-PACKAGE called [ng2-search-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter), this will definitely help you.

1. You should install the package -> npm i ng2-search-filter --save
2. Import the module in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app';
 
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter'; // <-- HERE
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, Ng2SearchPipeModule], // <-- HERE
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then you should create a search field:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
```

in your component.ts file declare the searchText variable as public.

```
<option *ngFor="let c of wslrList.result | filter: searchText">{{c.A}}</option>
```

when typing something in the search field you should see your dropdown being filter by the typed letter/number (anything typed).

Comment: where should i add that ng2-search-filter in above code

Comment: will try it !  Thanks for help

Comment: if you've learned programming, you should be able to make it work with that package, everything is documented.